# box wont maximize further

Tags: c#

I have this app written in C# and it won't maximize further even though the code forcefully specifies the size, the window doesn't follow it. Other windows app follows the size that I specified but this one doesn't (been figuring what might go wrong but it seems a bug). Thanks stackoverflow

[image]

As you can see, the running window is not following explicitly what the code tells. The displayed window should be way larger than the current size.

Comment: Does the design-time size of the form fall within the minimum and maximum sizes?

Comment: The size of the form in the Visual Studio form designer.

Comment: What is the design-time size of the form, wavepacket?

Comment: 416,214 is the design-time size sir @WillA

Comment: here... http://puu.sh/1whoM

Comment: 416x214 does not fit within the minimum and maximum bounds - try resizing your form in the designer to e.g. 442x265 so that it at least starts out at the minimum size.

Comment: i tried,, heres it.. http://puu.sh/1whuR  but still http://puu.sh/1whuR serious bug in c#

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20436/discussion-between-will-a-and-vvavepacket)